# Detail screen dispatcher error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a home screen where I'm asking the user to enter a number. In the back of that screen I simply search the DB for this number and if its a perfect match I send the user directly to that detail screen. The first time always works, but on the second time around I get an error that says "An error has occurred while running this screen. Error details: Screen 'DaFileDetail' is not loaded yet.'

After I click Close Screen I get another error from the home screen saying Invalid Operation: Dispatcher has been stopped. I cannot seem to understand whats going on here. I do other searches that aren't precise and everything works great and smooth but when I do a search that has a hit of 1 I get these errors each time. My code below has dispatcher check access and all but even without this it doesn't work:

```
this.DAFiles.Load();
if (DAFiles.Count == 1)
{

    if (Details.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Application.ShowDAFileDetail(this.DAFiles.FirstOrDefault().Id);
    }
    else
    {
        Details.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {

            Application.ShowDAFileDetail(this.DAFiles.FirstOrDefault().Id);

        });
    }

}
else if (DAFiles.Count == 0)
    this.ShowMessageBox("No search results found");

else
{
    this.OpenModalWindow("SearchDA");
}
```

My entity is set to the default properties only thing that I've changed is the paging.

Comment: Code for ShowDAFileDetail ?

Comment: Thats part of the Lightswitch API, nothing I coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the detail screen you cant have FindControls I had to move them to _Created() Method. Everything works now.